# Tbody scrollbar

Tags: html

In my html file the table height was limited say(100px;) but the tbody has more rows. I need scroll bar to appear for tbody.

no div must place between header and body? I need to implement this in all browser (FF,IE7,IE8,safari)

Answer (score 3):

Here's something called [Cross-browser scrolling tbody](http://www.gtalbot.org/DHTMLSection/ScrollingTBody.html). Haven't tried it but hope it helps.

Comment: It's a fake! The whole table scrolls, not the tbody. The header is a separate table, so it's not semantic markup. Also it requires you to have predefined column widths. Other than that it's fine...